# oracle | rename columns with case

Tags: oracle

I have a table defined as this:

```
CREATE TABLE GENERAL_STATISTICS.PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT3
(
  NAME    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  START_TIME   DATE,
  END_TIME     DATE,
  ROWS_LOADED  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
)
```

[image]

Well I want to rename PPLP IMPORT DATA to something else eg 'Report1'

with case statement but it does not work.

```
SELECT PPLP_NAME,
  (CASE
     WHEN PPLP_NAME='PPLP IMPORT DATA' THEN 'BSCS_PPL_IMP_INVOICE'
     WHEN PPLP_NAME='PPLP IMPORT DATA FOR RERUN' THEN 'BSCS_PPL_IMP_USAGE_RERUN'
  END)
FROM  PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT3
```

Comment: Your table `PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT3` has no column called `PPLP_NAME`. Did you mean `NAME`? Also in database terms, renaming a column means permanently changing the definition of the table column, e.g. changing `ROWS_LOADED` to `ROWS_PROCESSED`. You are not doing that here.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you mean by "...but it does not work". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just missing the `ELSE`?

```
SELECT PPLP_NAME,
  (CASE
     WHEN PPLP_NAME='PPLP IMPORT DATA' THEN 'BSCS_PPL_IMP_INVOICE'
     WHEN PPLP_NAME='PPLP IMPORT DATA FOR RERUN' THEN 'BSCS_PPL_IMP_USAGE_RERUN'
     ELSE PPLP_NAME
  END)
FROM  PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT3
```

But you now say you just want one columns, so that would be:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN PPLP_NAME='PPLP IMPORT DATA' THEN 'BSCS_PPL_IMP_INVOICE'
       WHEN PPLP_NAME='PPLP IMPORT DATA FOR RERUN' THEN 'BSCS_PPL_IMP_USAGE_RERUN'
       ELSE PPLP_NAME
       END as PPLP_NAME
FROM  PPLP_LOAD_GENSTAT3
```

Comment: No this is not working as expected! it creates a new column!

Comment: Of course it does, you didn't explain that it should not!

Comment: Ok, please let me know how this would work without creating a new column

Comment: Sir, you are the best! :)